# Write on Slave redis db

Tags: redis

I have a master redis server (S1) and I have 6 other servers. I want them to have local redis slaves, so any change on the redis master will be replicated to the slaves on each local server

Can I write on a slave and make this one update the master, and then the master will update the other slaves?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://redis.io/topics/replication

Answer (score 14):

You can disable read-only mode on a slave, but the writes to the slave will be ephemeral and discarded when the slave resynchronizes or is restarted.

Also this feature will possibly be dropped in the future.

See http://redis.io/topics/replication#read-only-slave

Answer (score 0):

Create a cluster instead. This video shows how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8BkmdZzxDg