# (error) READONLY You can't write against a read only replica

Tags: php, redis

I installed Redis and phpredis, it was working fine. I tested the below code in PHP, after that, I'm not able to add/set anything. It shows only "(error) READONLY You can't write against a read-only replica."

My added code:

```
$redis->slaveOf('10.0.1.7', 6379);
$redis->lastSave();
```

I'm wondering what's wrong in this. assist me to get rid off this issue

Comment: You can only read from slaves by default, as the error says. See https://redis.io/topics/replication#read-only-slave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write on Slave redis db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829163/write-on-slave-redis-db)